# What is the name of the soundtrack on the Juiced start menu?

Tags: game-music-identification, juiced

I'm asking about an old racing game called [*Juiced*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juiced_%28video_game%29) (2005).

I honestly have tried to look all over the soundtracks of *Juiced*, it is the first soundtrack you hear when you boot up *Juiced* on the Xbox/PC/PS2, I don't know what the soundtrack is called.

This [page](http://gaming.wikia.com/wiki/Juiced/soundtrack) I looked at doesn't include the menu soundtrack - I put them all on YouTube and none of them is what I am looking for.

Can anyone name the soundtrack, I will appreciate it so much!

*If you do not know the name of the soundtrack but you have a specific link e.g. YouTube, then that would be just fine.*

Comment: When you say soundtrack, it sounds like you mean to ask about a specific song, correct? There's [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G5nI0BiuDc) on youtube, but I'm guessing you've seen it.

Comment: @DoozerBlake That's good, but the soundtrack isn't on the list. It's a menu soundtrack that goes on around the game menu but never in-game.

Comment: This guy's at the menu, although he's talking over the song: http://youtu.be/tOz-SMDfe-M?t=2m41s  is this the track you're talking about?  it sounds more like just something simple they put together for the game.

Comment: Yes, that's it. I'm looking for that, surely there might be a rip on the CD, I'm looking for that.

Comment: Just from listening to the clip linked by @agent86, I am pretty sure that the menu "music" is a mere 7-8 second sound clip that loops (4 base like synths followed by something that sounds like cymbals...). I doubt something like this would warrant a spot in any sort of soundtrack, so it probably doesn't have a name. It also doesn't seem like the sort of thing people would bother to rip and put online (seeing how short it is).

Comment: Have you tried searching [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) for the Juiced soundtrack or tried a music ID smartphone app like Shazam?

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, this is not a soundtrack from any released music. It's a standard game-sound-design, designed by Andrew Diey when he was working as a sound designer for Juice Games, before they were bought by THQ.
The beat is titled Menu Theme.